# test class for the Wsdl2apex class

Tags: wsdl2apex

I have a wsdl2apex class which resembes like this.

```
public class wwwmysiteComsfdcContract {
    public class sfdcContractWSDLSOAPQSPort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://sfdc2-osb-dit.us.mysite.com:80/sfdc/Contract/Services';
        public Map < String, String > inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map < String, String > outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        public wwwmysiteComsfdcGilHeaderdataxmlsCONTRACT.headerData_element request_header;
        private String request_header_hns = 'headerData=http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/GIL/HeaderDataXMLS';
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[] {
            'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/types', 'wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes', 'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/', 'wwwmysiteComsfdcContract', 'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/GetContractDetails/types', 'wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet', 'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/GIL/HeaderDataXMLS', 'wwwmysiteComsfdcGilHeaderdataxmlsCONTRACT', 'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/CreateMessage', 'wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage'
        };
        public wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchResultType Search_x(String Region, String ContractNumber, String ssnum, String PhoneNumber, String CreditApplicationNumber, String SerialTagNumber, String InvoiceNumber, String mysiteOrderNumber, String ContactName, String TaxIdNumber, String PONumber, String CustomerName, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.Pagination_element Pagination) {
            wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchRequestType request_x = new wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchRequestType();
            request_x.Region = Region;
            request_x.ContractNumber = ContractNumber;
            request_x.ssnum = ssnum;
            request_x.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
            request_x.CreditApplicationNumber = CreditApplicationNumber;
            request_x.SerialTagNumber = SerialTagNumber;
            request_x.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber;
            request_x.mysiteOrderNumber = mysiteOrderNumber;
            request_x.ContactName = ContactName;
            request_x.TaxIdNumber = TaxIdNumber;
            request_x.PONumber = PONumber;
            request_x.CustomerName = CustomerName;
            request_x.Pagination = Pagination;
            wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchResultType response_x;
            Map < String, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchResultType > response_map_x = new Map < String, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchResultType > ();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            this,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[] {
                endpoint_x,
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/Search',
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/types',
                    'SearchRequest',
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/types',
                    'SearchResponse',
                    'wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchResultType'
            });
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x;
        }
        public wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsResponseType GetContractDetails(String Region, String ContractNumber) {
            wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsRequestType request_x = new wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsRequestType();
            request_x.Region = Region;
            request_x.ContractNumber = ContractNumber;
            wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsResponseType response_x;
            Map < String, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsResponseType > response_map_x = new Map < String, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsResponseType > ();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            this,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[] {
                endpoint_x,
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/GetContractDetails/types',
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/GetContractDetails/types',
                    'GetContractDetailsRequest',
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/GetContractDetails/types',
                    'GetContractDetailsResponse',
                    'wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsResponseType'
            });
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x;
        }
        public wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CreateMessageResponseType CreateMessage(Boolean asynchronous, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.RegionType Region, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CommentsType Comments) {
            wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CreateMessageRequestType request_x = new wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CreateMessageRequestType();
            request_x.asynchronous = asynchronous;
            request_x.Region = Region;
            request_x.Comments = Comments;
            wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CreateMessageResponseType response_x;
            Map < String, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CreateMessageResponseType > response_map_x = new Map < String, wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CreateMessageResponseType > ();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            this,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[] {
                endpoint_x,
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/CreateMessage/action',
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/CreateMessage',
                    'CreateMessageRequest',
                    'http://www.mysite.com/sfdc/Contract/CreateMessage',
                    'CreateMessageResponse',
                    'wwwmysiteComsfdcContractCreatemessage.CreateMessageResponseType'
            });
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x;
        }
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
private class ContractMockCalloutTest {
    testmethod static void SFDCGatewayWSDLSOAPQSPort_SearchCustomerContractTest() {
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new ContractListMockWebServiceCallout());
        wwwmysiteComsfdcContract.wwwmysiteComsfdcContract stub = new wwwmysiteComsfdcContract.wwwmysiteComsfdcContract();
        //Here I am stuck, I am not able to access the inner class and its methods in the WSDL2Apex class in test class.
```

//if I refer stub.innerclass it is throwing error any thoughts what I am doing wrong.
        }
    }

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you're stuck?

Comment: @LaceySnr isTest
private class ContractMockCalloutTest {
    testmethod static void SFDCGatewayWSDLSOAPQSPort_SearchCustomerContractTest() {
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new ContractListMockWebServiceCallout());
        wwwmysiteComsfdcContract.wwwmysiteComsfdcContract stub = new wwwmysiteComsfdcContract.wwwmysiteComsfdcContract();
        //Here I am stuck when I refer the following line it is throwing the error as invalid type   stub.wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchResultType and how to make a move from here no Idea please let me know.
    }
}

Comment: @LaceySnr After Initalising the outer class I am not able to invoke or access the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see, your base example up top doesn't match your stub class you instantiate in the test.  Note the extra "Contract" before WSDLSOAPQSPort.

Comment: I corrected that and I did not have any idea to go further if possible please suggest me some thing to go further.

Answer (score 0):

For inner classes you can do it it by creating an instance of the Outer class in the test as below.

```
public class classA {
    public class classB  {
       public void doSomething(){
         ---some code----
    }
  }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class TestClassA {
  static {
    // This should get code coverage on inner class
    new ClassA();
  }     
  @isTest static void testSomethingInClassB() {
    ClassA.ClassB b = new ClassA.ClassB();
    b.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: its is throwing error as classB is invalid.

Comment: Hey Saroj I updated my class with actual class can you please let me know what I can do further.

Answer (score 0):

Your test will want to create an instance of the port class.

```
wwwmysiteComsfdcContract.sfdcContractWSDLSOAPQSPort stub = 
    new wwwmysiteComsfdcContract.sfdcContractWSDLSOAPQSPort();
wwwmysiteComsfdcContractGetcontractdet.GetContractDetailsResponseType result =
    stub.GetContractDetails('Region', 'ContractNumber');


wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.Pagination_element pagination = new wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.Pagination_element();
// More code here to setup pagination
wwwmysiteComsfdcContractTypes.SearchResultType searchResult = 
    stub. Search_x('Region', 'ContractNumber', 'ssnum', 'PhoneNumber', 
                   'CreditApplicationNumber', 'SerialTagNumber', 'InvoiceNumber',
                   'mysiteOrderNumber', 'ContactName', 'TaxIdNumber', 'PONumber', 
                   'CustomerName', pagination);
```

If you are mostly after code coverage for the generated Wsdl2Apex classes, [I've made a tool that will do this for you](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer). There is an option when generating the Apex classes to also generate the test methods to give you coverage.